# Installing Tkinter error with google-webdesigner

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter

I was installing tkinter on Ubuntu.But it showed me this message.So i tried  re-installing "gconf" but none of them are working as the google web-designer is not getting installed.Can anybody help me with a solution? 
Thanks in advance.

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-webdesigner.postinst: 46: /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-webdesigner.postinst: gconftool-2: not found
```

dpkg: error processing package google-webdesigner (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
  Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-webdesigner
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: `tkinter` should be preinstalled with Python and you don't have to instal it.How did you check if it us not installed? what command did you use to install it? did you use `sudo`? Do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: it is not pre installed. using  preinstalled python 2. i used      sudo.

Comment: only once I saw (the newest) Ubuntu with Python but without Tkinter. I had to install `apt python-tk`. BTW: you can install Python 3 and still keep Python 2 for system. On Linux Mint based on Ubuntu I have now Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 but earlier I had also 2.6 and  2.3 at the same time. [unofficial python repo for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Comment: I installed 3 but still the error showed up.So i read up in a blog and tried to changed the google-webdesigner.postrm file by adding permission but the files could not be updated because it did not allow to change the permission.

Comment: The error obviously tells you that `gconftool-2` is not found.  For ubuntu, use `sudo apt-get install gconf2` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps

1. `sudo apt purge google-webdesigner`
2. `sudo apt install gdebi`
3. `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`
4. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo gdebi google-webdesigner_current_amd64.deb`

You can run the commands in Downloads and now your google-webdesigner should be working